# Colab Error :Could not fetch csv file from backend

Tags: pandas, csv, machine-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory

i am trying to open **csv file in google colab** with (7501, 20) rows and column respectively .I have worked with the same file before it have worked then. but now it's throwing error "Could not fetch csv file from backend"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am unable to open/check my dataset to get insight from data in google colaboratary.It's throwing the error as "Could not fetch ABC.csv file from backend